# Parsing an array of hashes into a tree structure

Tags: ruby

I have this structure in Ruby:

```
[
  {“type"=>"Action", "parameterized"=>false, "groups"=>["feed"], "value"=>"feed”},
  {"type"=>"State", "parameterized"=>true, "groups"=>["group"], "value"=>"group:%1s”},
  {"type"=>"Action", "parameterized"=>false, "groups"=>["challenge", "build"], "value"=>"challenge:build”},
  {"type"=>"Action", "parameterized"=>false, "groups"=>["challenge", "decorate"], "value"=>"challenge:decorate”},
  {"type"=>"Action", "parameterized"=>false, "groups"=>["report"], "value"=>"report”},
  {"type"=>"Action", "parameterized"=>false, "groups"=>["report", "complete"], "value"=>"report:complete”},
]
```

The elements in the array can come in any order, and I want it to be parsed into a tree structure so that if there are matching groups (each groups array do come in order where the first is the root and the next is a child of the first and the next again is the child of the one before and so on) are merged into the same branch in the tree. If there is a "parameterized" parameter, this also result in a extra branch in the tree. I want the structure above to end up line the following:

```
{
  "Action" => {
    "feed" => {
      "value" => "feed"
    },
    "challenge" => {
      "build" => {
        "value" => "challenge:build"
      }
      "decorate" => {
        "value" => "challenge:decorate"
      }
    },
    "report" => {
      "value" => "report",
      "complete" => {
        "value" => "report:complete"
      }
    }
  },
  "State" => {
    "group" => {
      "parameterized" => {
        "value" => "group:%1s"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea. how to do this in Ruby?

Best regards
Søren

Comment: Any idea?—Sure. You should write the code, that traverses the original tree and produces the desired one.

Comment: Yes, I just can't get my head around it. Would you make a recursive function here or just iterate over the group arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let’s define the proc that will be finding buried groups inside the same type

```
deep_find = ->(hash, name) {
  hash.detect { |k, v| k == name || v.is_a?(Hash) && deep_find.(v, name) }
}
```

Now we are ready to walk through the input hash either appending a tail to the *found* key or inserting the new key.

Objects in Ruby are mutable, and that will help us a lot; traversing the beast we’ll detect the needed hash and modify it inplace. This changes will be reflected in the whole.

```
input.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = h.dup.clear }) do |h, acc|
  # let’s dig into the hash and find the _branch_ of interest
  #   it will return the hash _or_ `nil`
  buried = deep_find.(acc[h['type']], '')
  # if the target was found, we pivk it up for further modifications
  #   otherwise we start from the top level
  target = buried ? buried.last : acc[h['type']]
  # going down the tree of groups; each call to `inner[g]`
  #   will produce the nested hash, thanks to `default_proc`
  #   of the accumulator
  target = h['groups'].reduce(target) { |inner, g| inner[g] }
  # determine whether we should wrap the value with `parametrized`
  #   and eventually set it
  (h['parameterized'] ? target['parameterized'] : target)['value'] = h['value']
end
#⇒ {"type1"=>{"group1"=>{"group2"=>{"value"=>"value1",
#      "group7"=>{"group8"=>{"parameterized"=>{"value"=>"value3"}}}}}},
#   "type2"=>{"group3"=>{"group4"=>{"group5"=>{"value"=>"value2"}}}}}
```

*NB* the trick with accumulator’s default proc (`Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = h.dup.clear }`) allows not to bother with new values initialization, no matter how deep they are.

Comment: It perfectly works on the test data you have provided. It would not be complicated to adapt it to any similar case.

Comment: Yes it does, on my "real" data I get duplicated groups, but the comment field will not contain my example, so I will update my question. But Aleksei, would you mind describing the code to me in quite a lot of detail? I am new to Ruby, and it almost look like black magic to me. I understand the deep_find I think, it traverses down to find the element with "name". But the rest is magic... :) I would prefer if you can describe the code, and then I can change my version of it to make it work with my "real" data.

Comment: I fixed the error (it traversed down from the second group only, assuming there could not be dups on the topmost level,) and dropped some comments.